# When user input matches up with one bit in list, print something, if not then print something else

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and coding in general. currently trying to make a program that asks the user for a code, and if the code matches up with one of the bits in the list then it prints saying the code was accepted and quits the program. otherwise it says the code is invalid and loops back to the user input.

The issue I have is that it asks the user for the code and regardless of what is inputted it says it is invalid

```
codes = ['1234', '5678', '2684', '1243', '3565', '3458', '4589']
truecode = False

while not truecode:

    user_input = input('Please input your code')

    if user_input is codes:
        print('Code accepted, enjoy your voucher')

    else:
        print('Code is invalid, please try again')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `in` instead of `is`:

```
if user_input in codes:
    print('Code accepted, enjoy your voucher')
else:
    print('Code is invalid, please try again')
```

Comment: Also, you might want to add ```truecode = True``` at the end to stop the program.

Comment: perfect, fixed it :)